# Failed to resolve dependencies on Grails

Tags: java, grails, dependencies

i just installed Grails 2.5.0. Anytime I try to run it, it displays the following message:

```
             Resolve error obtaining dependencies: Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.groovy for more information):

- cglib:cglib-nodep:2.2.2


and then run the dependency - report:
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
        :: cglib#cglib-nodep;2.2.2: not found
        ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

| Obtaining dependency data....
| Error Error executing script DependencyReport: : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Report file '/home/mballeng91/.grails/ivy-cache/org.grails.internal-mballeng91-build.xml' does not exist. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

Use version 2.5.4 (and in general use the latest patch version available to avoid discovering lots of already-fixed bugs), it has the correct repo information and dependency resolution logic.

Comment: I get this same error with 2.5.4, 2.5.5, and 2.5.6. :-(